# Why is the singular “Olympic Athlete From Russia” used for an ice-hockey team?

Tags: grammatical-number, sports, political-correctness, politics

It’s definitely more than one athlete in the Russian team. 
On TV:

[image: on TV]

[On the web](https://www.eurosport.com/ice-hockey/pyeongchang/2018/live-olympic-athlete-from-russia-norway_mtc996574/live.shtml)

[image]

And they did it all the time till the finals:

[image]

Clearly, it wasn't an arbitrary error or slip-up.

Comment: They've probably adopted a one-size-fits-all policy. Never works. But POB.

Comment: My vote goes for *typo*. Do you fear/think it might be correct in English? Why? It seems odd that one team is *Norway* while the Russian team is called *Olympic Athlete From Russia*. Definitely, someone in the newsroom pressed a wrong button.

Comment: Not a typo, imo. It goes like this for many days. Also there is alink at the bottom of the question—repeated 10 times over there.

Comment: It's a translation error. Your link is set at "International English", and someone must have used OAR as a placeholder. The team is Russia see this link on the same website https://www.eurosport.com/ice-hockey/pyeongchang/2018/russians-sing-banned-anthem-after-beating-germany-to-ice-hockey-gold_sto6654076/story.shtml

Comment: OK, Russia isn't Russia, something to do with sanctions due to alleged doping abuse by the squad (can you tell I'm really informed about the Olympic games!)

Comment: Russia is not being considered as an entity because of past doping problems. So athletes are designated as coming from Russia but are not considered a Russian team. But they have forgotten to add the plural. I think.

Comment: Given they’re doing it consistently all the time during TV broadcasts, it doesnt look like they’ve simply “forgotten “.  Looks odd.

Comment: The official [Olympic website](https://www.olympic.org/pyeongchang-2018/results/en/curling/athlete-profile-ncurxteam2-oar01-olympic-athlete-from-russia.htm) also has this quirk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Olympic Athlete from Russia is the offical English name of the team,** although it is widely misrepresented as *Olympic Athletes from Russia* in a variety of outlets, as *athletes* would indeed be the far more natural choice.

[image: Olympic Athlete from Russia logo]

I would note that the official French name is Athlète Olympique de Russie— also singular, and also widely referred to in the plural (*athlètes olympiques*) in French news media.

The singular designation thus seems to be intentional, although *why* it was chosen is a matter the IOC has not divulged. Perhaps this logo and team name appearing on the uniforms would underscore that the wearer is an individual athlete, and not part of a delegation— that is, that OAR is not simply RUS by another name.

Names are names, and aren't required to be natural, or grammatical, or semantically logical, or to follow any other rules, and official names don't necessarily correspond to names found in everyday usage. Prior to this designation, O.A.R. as an initialism was arguably most famous as the name of a band, Of A Revolution, which doesn't really "make sense" to me as a name either.

If you follow the Olympic movement it would not surprise you to see other unusual entries in the list of [Olympic programs](https://www.olympic.org/pyeongchang-2018/results/en/general/noc-schedule.htm) competing in the Pyeongchang games. Olympic Athlete from Russia is no less jarring than Former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia marching in under *F* when the games are hosted in English-speaking countries, or the even older Chinese Taipei.

Comment: I don't follow sports but presumably this has to do with the mass doping ban, such that there isn't really a team representing Russia in the normal way

Comment: @ChrisH Yes, that is correct.